# My ajax function failed to store data into sql server

Tags: model-view-controller

I have a JQuery login/register modal in my mvc web application and I'm trying to store the new user in the simplest form at this stage, so now I know that I must use Ajax to send the information to the server but something is wrong and it is not working
so here is my modal:

```
 <!--Signin/Signup container-->
        <div id="modal" class="popupContainer" style="display:none;">


            <section class="popupBody">
                <!-- Social Login -->
                <div class="social_login">
                    <div class="">
                        <a href="#" class="social_box fb">
                            <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>
                            <span class="icon_title">سجل عن طريق الفيس بوك</span>

                        </a>

                        <a href="#" class="social_box google">
                            <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></span>
                            <span class="icon_title">سجل عن طريق كوكل</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="centeredText">
                        <span>أو استخدم الايميل الخاص بك</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="action_btns">
                        <div  class="one_half"><a href="#" id="login_form" class="btn">سجل دخول</a></div>
                        <div class="one_half last"><a href="#" id="register_form" class="btn"> انضم</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Username & Password Login form -->
                <div class="user_login">
                    <form>
                        <label>الايميل / اسم المستخدم</label>
                        <input type="text" />
                        <br />

                        <label>كلمة السر</label>
                        <input type="password" />
                        <br />

                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input id="remember" type="checkbox" />
                            <label for="remember">احفظ معلومات الدخول على هذا الجهاز</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="action_btns">
                            <div class="one_half"><a href="#" class="btn back_btn"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i> رجوع</a></div>
                            <div id="login_btn" class="one_half last"><a href="#" class="btn btn_red">Login</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    <a href="#" class="forgot_password">هل نسيت كلمة المرور؟</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Register Form -->
                <div class="user_register">
                    <form>
                        <label>اسم المستخدم</label>
                        <input id="txtUserName" type="text" />
                        <br />

                        <label>عنوان البريد الألكتروني</label>
                        <input id="txtEmail" type="email" />
                        <br />

                        <label>كلمة المرور</label>
                        <input id="txtPass" type="password" />
                        <br />

                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input id="send_updates" type="checkbox" />
                            <label for="send_updates">أرسل لي رسائل في حال وجود أي تحديثات</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="action_btns">
                            <div class="one_half"><a href="#" class="btn back_btn"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i> Back</a></div>
                            <div id="register_btn" class="one_half last"><a href="#" class="btn btn_red">Register</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <!--Signin/Signup End-->
```

and this is my script

```
<script>
            //login code
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#register_btn").click(function () {
                    // Do something
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("Register", "Account")',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {//passing data
                            userName:$("#txtUserName").val(),
                            email:$("#txtEmail").val(),
                            password: $("#txtPass").val()
                        },
                        success: function () {
                            alert('success');
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert('failure');
                        }

                    });


                });
            });
        </script>
```

and here is my controller code

```
        public ActionResult Register()
    {

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(UserModel user)
    {
        AddDetails(user);
        return View();
    }

    private void Connection()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NerdsContext"].ToString();
        con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    }

    //Add records to database
    private void AddDetails(UserModel user)
    {
        Connection();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("AddUser", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", user.userName);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", user.email);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", user.password);

        con.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

I checked my sql procedure it is working fine but I don't know why I'm getting failure alert.

Comment: Ajax is Sent > Received > Parsed > Stored.  Check each of those steps and you should find an answer.  You browser network inspector is the send, your web server is the receive and parse.

Comment: Hi salRad. Are you using Chrome? You may want to check the developer tools (F12) in Chrome to make sure there are no javascript errors.

Comment: OK thanks guys I'll check things out

Comment: OK that is sooo weird I've been trying for a whole day and nothing now and after I posted this it is working, I have no Idea why!!!
maybe it is the browser just like you said @AnotherDeveloper